# XPath of element containing N number of a certain character?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I want the XPath of an element whose `@id` contains 3 hyphens.

e.g. I want to select the second element below

```
<a id="X-X"></a>
<a id="X-X-X-X"></a>
<a id="X-X-X"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XPath 2.0

This XPath 2.0 expression,

```
//a[matches(@id, "^([^-]*-){3}[^-]*$")]
```

will select all `a` elements with `id` attributes that have 3 `-` characters in its value.  It can easily be adapted to count characters other than `-` or to require certain characters to be between the `-` characters.

### XPath 1.0

This XPath 1.0 expression,

```
//a[string-length(@id) - string-length(translate(@id,"-","")) = 3]
```

will select all `a` elements with `id` attributes that have 3 `-` characters in its value.